# custom setting in Apex Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, customsetting, bulkification

I have one custom setting country name and capital.
I have created a one trigger which will set the description(capital) based on country_Information picklist.

```
trigger FetchCapitalUsingCustomsett on Account (before insert,before update) {
    Map<string,CountryInfo__c> MapCountryCapitals=CountryInfo__c.getAll();
    system.debug('MapCountryCapitals:::::::'+MapCountryCapitals);
    list<string> accCountry=new list<string>();
    for(account acc:trigger.new){
        CountryInfo__c mc =CountryInfo__c.getValues(acc.Country_information__c);
        acc.Description=mc.capital__c;
    }
}
```

The above is the code. How can I bulkify this code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code does not look like it will have any bulk issues. You do need to check if the setting is null though, since you are not guaranteed to have a `CountryInfo__c` record for a given key.

```
CountryInfo__c setting = CountryInfo__c.getValues(acc.Country_Information__c);
if (setting != null) acc.Description = setting.Capital__c;
```

I also strongly advise you to research [handler patterns](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices) and find one that works for you. It will make it much easier to adhere to one trigger per object best practice.